# cant select input button with id using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, button, onclick, click

I have the following code on my script file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#cancel_button").click(function(){
      alert("TEST");
   });
});
```

And in my site i have this:

```
<form id="edit_news_form" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="news_id" value="30">
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Título" value="TEXT" size="80"><br>
    <textarea name="text" placeholder="Texto" rows="20" cols="58">TEXT</textarea><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Tags" value="Tag1" name="tags" size="80"><br>
    <input id="edit_button" type="submit" value="Edit">
    <input id="cancel_button" type="button" value="Cancel">
</form>
```

Why i cant select the button and receive the alert?

-------------EDITED ------------

The problem is that i'm insert the html code dynamically with jquery...So i forget this detail.. for this work is necessary use:

```
$('#cancel_button').live('click', function);
```

Thank u all

Comment: Did you include the jQuery library? Did you include the script file? Your code looks fine.

Comment: Also when you say _select the button_ you actually clicked the button right?

Comment: Agree with Vega and NullPointer. Your code works fine. See this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/U37pA/

Comment: The problem is that i'm insert the html code dynamically with jquery...So i forget this detail.. for this work is necessary use: $('#cancel_button').live('click', function);.....Thank u all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery live method is deprecated since v1.7. Also behind the scene all the events like- live, click etc.. are calling the on method

so use this instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '#cancel_button', function () {
     // do some work
});
```

this will work whether your html is loaded dynamically or not